# Bash script to make a tree directories

Tags: linux, bash, mkdir

I have a script here, this script will list all directories in current working directory and create sub directories to make a directory tree but the problem is it can't create a directory.

Can anyone help me this out ? The script must create a directory in a specific directory and sub-directories

```
LIST=`ls -D`
for i in $LIST;
do
mkdir -p $i"/Dir3/Dir4/"
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Here is one way to "correctly" iterate over directories:

```
for dir in */; do
    #       ^-- the trailing slash makes $dir expand to directories only
    [ -d "${dir}" ] || continue
    mkdir -p "${dir}/Dir3/Dir4/"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LIST=`find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d`
for i in $LIST;
do
    mkdir -p $i/Dir3/Dir4
done
```

Comment: first, `find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d` means find all directories under current folder, and saves in LIST variable. second, iterate all directories, and mkdir subdirectories.

Comment: how can I make a script that will make a directory not in the current directory. For example in /var lets say .. I want to create a directory there . What is the right script for that ?

Comment: replace `find .` with `find /var`

Answer (score 0):

Do you ask something like this?

```
find * -type d -exec mkdir -p /var/abc/{} \;
```

It will take the directory and sub-directories from current folder, and create new same folders under /var/abc